# Are moderators privy to thread spy tool?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps it a bit of paranoia on my part (or rather a privacy concern) but I wanted to know if moderators have that privilege where they can see who is viewing which thread or voting on a particular thread?

My first impression would be no.

Comment: I just realized it may be suited for Stackoverflow question. Please migrate it if need be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Assuming such thread-spy tool as you described exists*:

**No**, moderators have no access to them.

*Does such thread-spy tool exist*?

Not for end users. For those with access to the database (Stack employees), however ...

Answer (score 7):

The elected community moderators or appointed pro-tem moderators cannot see who voted for which question. They also cannot see which posts your are looking at.

What they can see is an aggregated voting statistic for each user, so they can see e.g. if one user is spending most of it's upvotes or downvotes on a specific other user. The main use for this information is to help find sockpuppet accounts that were created to artificially inflate a user's reputation.

StackExchange employees with developer access can see single votes, but not easily on their own posts (they would have to manually check the database for that).